# Why do I get question which i'm not interested to answer?

Tags: support, tag-watching, homepage

These are my favorite tags:

> [image]

But I still get question like these

> [image]
>
> [image]

Can somebody tell me how I should configure my account so that I get questions related to my "favorite tags"?

or is it some kind of bug that I found out :) ?

Comment: The algorithm relies on questions you viewed in the past, about 50-50, not only on your favorite tags. You can see questions tagged with your favorite tags only by using the search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion